# zipWithIndex for nested collections (release without mutable state)

Tags: scala

There are some nested collections:

```
val xs = List(
           List("a","b"), 
           List("c"), 
           List("d", "e", "f"))
```

I want to create unique index for nested list's elements:

```
val result = List(
         List(("a", 0), ("b", 1)), 
         List(("c", 2)),
         List(("d", 3), ("e", 4), ("f", 5)))
```

This is a bad solution (used mutable state):

```
val indexes:List[Int] = xs.flatten.zipWithIndex.map(_._2)
var idx = 0
val result = xs.map(_.map{ el =>
   val copy = (el, indexes(idx))
   idx = idx + 1
   copy
})
```

How to release this task without mutable state?

Comment: Just a note, using mutable state is not a bad solution, there are cases where you do want to use mutable states because they make your code more legible, in this case I would definitely use mutable states, is intuitive, simple and you don't create  too many variables or intermediate collections. Anyway for the sake of curiosity I would also like to see a purely functional solution.

Comment: And indeed, if we look at the source of zipWithIndex https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L1 we see.. a mutable current index!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1(using `fold`):

```
scala> xs.foldLeft((List[List[(String, Int)]](), 0)){ 
         case ((r, i), x) => (r:+x.zip(Stream.from(i)), i+x.size) 
       }._1
res1: List[List[(String, Int)]] = List(List((a,0), (b,1)), List((c,2)), List((d,3), (e,4), (f,5)))
```

Solution 2(using recursion)

```
scala> def deepZip[A](ls: List[List[A]], i: Int = 0): List[List[(A, Int)]] = ls match {
     |   case Nil => Nil
     |   case x::xs => x.zip(Stream.from(i)) :: deepZip(xs, i+x.size)
     | }
deepZip: [A](ls: List[List[A]], i: Int)List[List[(A, Int)]]

scala> deepZip(xs)
res2: List[List[(String, Int)]] = List(List((a,0), (b,1)), List((c,2)), List((d,3), (e,4), (f,5)))
```

Solution 3:

```
scala> (xs, xs.map(_.size).scanLeft(0){ _+_ }).zipped map { (a, b) => a.zip(Stream.from(b)) }
res3: List[List[(String, Int)]] = List(List((a,0), (b,1)), List((c,2)), List((d,3), (e,4), (f,5)))
```

Comment: #1 was my first thought.  #3 is nice precomputing b, and easy on the eyes.  Less efficient variant, but easy on the eyes and the brain: `xs.zipWithIndex map { case (xx, i) => xx zip (Stream from xs.take(i).map(_.size).sum) }`

Answer (score 3):

Yet another variation:

```
val index = Iterator.from(0)
for (sl <- xs) yield for (e <- sl) yield (e, index.next)
```

Quite neat, IMO, but iterators aren't pure functional, of course

And a functional one, quite readable (to me, anyway)

```
 val starts = xs.scanLeft(0)(_ + _.size)
 (xs, starts, starts.tail).zipped map{ (sl, start, end) => sl zip ( start until end)}
```

Comment: This is nice. You can shorten it by embedding the second for loop in the first one: `for (sl <- xs; e <- sl) yield (e, index.next)`

Comment: @IonutGStan, no, you can't. That ends up flattening the list.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
def iterate(someList: List[List[Int]], counter: Int = 0, acc: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List()): List[List[(Int, Int)]] = someList match {
  case head :: tail =>
    val newCounter = counter + head.length
    val sublist = head.zipWithIndex.map {
      // add the counter to the index
      case (v, i) => (v, i + counter)
    }
    // recurse
    iterate(tail, newCounter, acc :+ sublist)
  case _ => acc
}

scala> iterate(List(List(1,2), List(3,4)))
res3: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,0), (2,1)), List((3,2), (4,3)))

scala> iterate(List(List(1,2), List(3,4), List(5)))
res4: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,0), (2,1)), List((3,2), (4,3)), List((5,4)))
```

What this basically does is iterate a list of lists, zip with the index each sublist and add a counter value which takes into account all the previous list lengths, when the list is empty we return an accumulator.

But as I said, I wouldn't trade this with the mutable version.

Comment: Isn't `acc.:+(foo)` syntax only used in obscure compiler debug output? `acc :+ sublist`

Comment: as one-liner: `def zipdeep[A](xx: List[List[A]], count: Int = 0, res: List[List[(A, Int)]] = Nil): List[List[(A, Int)]] = xx match { case a :: b => zipdeep(b, count+a.size, res :+ (a.zipWithIndex map { case (v,i) => (v,i+count) })) case _ => res }`

Comment: Strangely enough I sometime use the point (like with `.:+`) and sometimes not (like with `++`), as for the one liner, I had something like that in a first answer, I then moved all code in variables to make it more readable.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty strange. I only tried the one-liner to see if it shows how tidy the recursion is. Somewhere Odersky says folds are often simpler as a recursive func.

Answer (score 2):

You can always apply sufficient brute force to transform an imperative while loop to a functional `foldLeft`:

```
val xs = List(List("a", "b"), List("c"), List("d", "e", "f"))

def addIndeces(xs: List[List[String]]): List[List[(String, Int)]] = {
  val outerLoopState = 0 -> Vector.empty[List[(String, Int)]]

  val (finalCounter, finalResult) = xs.foldLeft(outerLoopState) {
    case ((counter, result), sublist) =>
      val innerLoopState = counter -> Vector.empty[(String, Int)]
      val (newCounter, subResult) = sublist.foldLeft(innerLoopState) {
        case ((counter, subResult), element) =>
          (counter + 1, subResult :+ (element, counter))
      }

      (newCounter, result :+ subResult.toList)
  }

  finalResult.toList
}

// scala> addIndeces(xs)
// res0: List[List[(String, Int)]] = List(List((a,0), (b,1)), List((c,2)), List((d,3), (e,4), (f,5)))
```

I've used `Vector` for the intermediate results to get more a efficient functional `append` operation. With `List` I would have had to prepend and then reverse the intermediate results.

Comment: That's a lot of LOC (ALOLOC?) compared to @Eastsun.

Answer (score 1):

Plain not tail recursive...

```
 def zipFrom[A](start:Int)(l:List[A]):(List[(A,Int)],Int) = {
  val end = start + l.length
  val ys = l zip (start to end)
  ys -> end
 }

 def zp[A](xs:List[List[A]],acc:Int):List[List[(A,Int)]] = xs match {
  case Nil    => Nil
  case h :: t =>
   val (l,e) = zipFrom(acc)(h)
   l :: zp(t,e)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = 0
val lim = li.map {
  case l @ List(_*) =>
    val s = index
    index += l.length
    l.zip(s until index)
}
```

It works fast and simple

Comment: A few redundant bits there. `case l @List(_*)=>` can just be `l =>`, and there's no need for the `.toList` of the range.

Answer (score 0):

variation on @Archetypal Paul using map instead of for

```
val ys = Iterator.from(0)
val zs = xs.map { _.map ((_,ys.next)) }
```

variation using zip & iterator & map

```
val ys = xs.flatten.zipWithIndex.iterator
val zs = xs.map { _.map ( x=> ys.next) }
```